# I downloaded Scrabble game through software center but can not login

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded Scrabble successfully but anytime I try to launch it, there is a problem of login where I would be asked to put my hostname:port.

Please does anyone knows how to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the game PyScrabble, then it is an [online multiplayer game](http://pyscrabble.sourceforge.net/?q=about) and you need to connect to a PyScrabble server to play against other players.

You can try the <kbd>Find Public Server</kbd> to find one.

However, as PyScrabble [has not been maintained since 2007](http://pyscrabble.sourceforge.net/?q=help) there may not be any servers still around.